# rails - how to check if user has been a member for a month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

i was wondering how i could check if a user has been a member for over 1 month? i notice that rails created a created_at column. how can i check if the user has been a month old member?

thanks

i looked at doing things like 1.month.ago but wouldn't that keep changing from the current date? maybe my logic is kinda wrong in that. could i do something like...

```
user.created_at - 1.month.ago > 0
```

could i not do this subtraction comparison? or does that not make sense? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
(user.created_at + 1.month).past?
```

or

```
user.created_at <= 1.month.ago
```

Comment: Your first suggestion does not do what you think it does. `Time.parse("2012-06-07 20:07:22") + 1.month.ago` gives you `2054-10-17 18:29:10 -0400 `

Answer (score 4):

`user.created_at < 1.month.ago` should be fine.